# chapter style latex horizontal line

Tags: sectioning, chapters, rules, titlesec

I want a chapter style like this:

```
                            1
------chapter name-------------

      text text text text tex
      t text text text text t
```

I have come this far:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\xdash}[1][3em]{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{0.55pt}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Large}{\filleft\Huge\thechapter}{1ex}{\xdash[2em]}[]

\begin{document}

\chapter
{Introduction}

Text text text text

\end{document}
```

but I can not get it right. I want the horizontal line to be longer then the "normal" text and I want the line to be before and after the chapter name.

Comment: When you say "longer" do you mean all the page should be crossed by the line or only some cm on each side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Her's an option using the `explicit` option for `titlesec`; the title is placed inside a `varwidth` environment of maximum width `\textwidth`; the left rule is drawn with a standard `\rule` command and the right rule uses `\xrfill` from the `xhfill` package. Long titles (spanning more than one line) are centered with respect to the rules:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large}{\filleft\thechapter}{2ex}
  {\hspace*{\dimexpr-4em-10pt\relax}%
    \advance\hsize4em\advance\hsize10pt%
    \rule[0.5ex]{4em}{1pt}\hspace{10pt}%
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}\raggedright#1\end{varwidth}%
    \hspace{10pt}\xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}%
  }

\begin{document}

\chapter{A short title}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{A long title spanning several lines just to see the format in this case}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image of a short title:

[image]

An image of a long title:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Shorter code and easier to follow! How to i do if i want say my abstract page to have this kind of style also? I copied your code and changed from Chapter to Section, but of course these changes every section in my document. Can i use different settings for the section in different part of the document or how to i solve this in an easy way?

Comment: @Mike hard to say if you don't provide precise information on the structure of your document. How are you producing your abstracta? Is your abstract a section produced with `\section*`?

Comment: I am using for my abstract \begin{abstract}, begin{notation} for notation page, \tableofcontents for table of content page. These pages i would like a similar style like the chapters. The sections in the different chapters will i probably want to use some ordinary style. Hope that helps with explaining my document.

Comment: @Mike no, it doesn't help much. In your question you mentioned the `book` document class, and this class doesn't provide an `abstract` environment nor a `notation` environment. You can use different styles for sections in your document, but I need to know the exact structure used to give you the most effective alternative.

Comment: The problem is that i am using a class made by my university.

Comment: @Mike then, I think it would be better to open a fresh new question with this new requirement, providing a link to the class needed and showing a little mock-up document with the actual document class and in which you show the sectional units for which you want to change the style.

Comment: Ok, I will do that! Thx for the help. It was very useful!!!